# Parsing a csv file in Java

Tags: java, csv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parsing CSV in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908012/parsing-csv-in-java)

How to do I parse a csv file correctly in java?  There are cases where simple StringTokenizer doesn't work as in the example below:

```
xxx,"hello, this breaks you"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ostermiller.org](http://ostermiller.org/) has a [jar](http://ostermiller.org/utils/download.html) with nice utility-classes like [CSV-Parser/Writer](http://ostermiller.org/utils/CSV.html) etc.

Answer (score 8):

Try using a dedicated library for that, e.g.:

- http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

[JSaPar](https://github.com/org-tigris-jsapar/jsapar) is another library that will do the work for you. You can find a comprehensive list of other alternative libraries [here](https://org-tigris-jsapar.github.io/jsapar/links).

Answer (score 0):

[Java Data File Read/Write Utility](http://datafile.sourceforge.net/) is a very straight forward and easy to use library for reading/writing CSV files.

- Most important class's documentation - [DataFile](http://datafile.sourceforge.net/apidoc/com/infomata/data/DataFile.html)
- [Download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/datafile/files/datafile/datafile%201.4/datafile-1.4.zip/download)

Answer (score 0):

BeanIO can be used to bind CSV records to Java bean objects.  Visit http://beanio.org for details.