# Knowing delimiters for CSV file

Tags: java, csv, java.util.scanner

This may be a simple question but I have not been able to find a satisfactory answer. I am writing a class in Java that needs to take in a .csv file filled with doubles in three columns. Obviously a .csv file uses commas as the delimiters, but when I try setting them with my scanner, the scanner finds nothing. Any advice?

```
Scanner s = null;
try {
  s = new Scanner(source);
  //s.useDelimiter("[\\s,\r\n]+"); //This one works if I am using a .txt file
  //s.useDelimiter(", \n"); // This is what I thought would work for a .csv file
  ...
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  System.err.format("FileNotFoundException: %s%s", e);
} catch (IOException e) {
  System.err.format("IOException: %s%n", e);
}
```

A sample input would be:

12.3 11.2 27.0

0.5 97.1 18.3

etc.

Thank you for your time!

EDIT: fixed! Found the correct delimiters and realized I was using hasNextInt() instead of hasNextDouble(). /facepalm

Comment: Can you provide a sample line or two of your .csv file?

Comment: Sure. I will add it to my question

Comment: You might want to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908012/parsing-csv-in-java

Comment: I don't see any commas in your example inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
first,second,"the third",fourth,"the,fifth"
```

Should only be five - the last comma is in a quote block, which should not get split.

Don't reinvent the wheel. There are open source libraries to handle this behavior.

A quick google search yielded http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/ and I'm sure there's others.

Comment: Thank you. I thought it would be simpler to code it myself because the input will always be exactly the same

Comment: [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) is a good library that parses and generates a variety of CSV formats as well as Tab-delimited files.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to read each individual item, try:

```
s.useDelimiter(",");
```

Then `s.next()` would return an item from the CSV.

Answer (score 1):

Why have you got a \n in your CSV delimiter?  Java doesn't have a difference between CSV and TXT files, if they have the same content.

I would think you would want

```
s.useDelimiter(",");
```

or

```
s.useDelimiter("[\\s]+,[\\s\r\n]*");
```

Comment: I must say I prefer glowcoder's response to my own.  I used to have a homebrew CSV parser in our app and it caused me many headaches.

Answer (score 1):

There are several methods to workaround:

**Method 1:**
use conditional statements ( if-else / switch ) in file extension.

```
if(ext == 'csv') {
  s.useDelimiter(", \n");
} else if(ext == 'txt') {
  s.useDelimiter("[\\s,\r\n]+");
}
```

**Method 2:**
as other answers suggested, use this:

```
s.useDelimiter(",");
```