# Can you scrape a CSV using Jsoup?

Tags: java, csv, web-scraping, jsoup

I am looking for a `Java` tool to scrape a `CSV` from a website and then parse the data. [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) seems like a viable option. **Is there a way to scrape a `CSV` file and then save the information to a database using Jsoup?**

Or is it strictly for scraping `HTML` code? Thanks.

Comment: The [`Apache Commons CSV`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) is a new project this year for parsing and generating comma-separated values (CSV) and TAB-delimited files. Release 1.1 just arrived this month (2014-11). Similar to JSoup in that it uses a simple clean API to create objects representing the parsed data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it ain't gonna work. Look at the Jsoup description:

> **jsoup** is a Java library for working with real-world HTML. It provides a very convenient API for extracting and manipulating data, using the best of DOM, CSS, and jquery-like methods.
>
> jsoup implements the WHATWG HTML5 specification, and parses HTML to the same DOM as modern browsers do.

What you are asking for is **how to parse CSV file in Java**. This question might be helpful for you:

[Fast CSV parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857248/fast-csv-parsing)