# How to convert comma-separated String to List?

Tags: java, string, collections, split

Is there any built-in method in Java which allows us to convert comma separated String to some container (e.g array, List or Vector)? Or do I need to write custom code for that?

```
String commaSeparated = "item1 , item2 , item3";
List<String> items = //method that converts above string into list??
```

Comment: If you want to parse CSV see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908012/parsing-csv-in-java

Comment: @Raedwald That's not what OP asked for though

Comment: **ONLY** ColinD's answer is correct here, assuming you want an ArrayList as in the question title.  ArrayList (which is mutable) is totally different from List, which can be just a simple fixed list.

Comment: @Fattie - fair point, and fixed that - https://stackoverflow.com/a/34735419/744133

Comment: Java 8 solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46485179/1216775

Answer (score 1176, accepted):

**Convert comma separated String to List**

```
List<String> items = Arrays.asList(str.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
```

The above code splits the string on a delimiter defined as: `zero or more whitespace, a literal comma, zero or more whitespace` which will place the words into the list and collapse any whitespace between the words and commas.

---

Please note that this returns simply a wrapper on an array: you ***CANNOT*** for example `.remove()` from the resulting `List`.  For an actual `ArrayList` you must further use `new ArrayList<String>`.

Comment: @rosch Its a regular expression (regex). `\s` matches any white space, The `*` applies the match zero or more times. So `\s*` means "match any white space zero or more times". We look for this before and after the comma. Therefore, the split will work for strings like `"item1 , item2 , item3"`, or `"item1,item2 ,item3"`, etc. In Java, you need to escape the backslash in strings, so you get `\\s*`

Comment: @andreyne `" item1 , item2 , item3 , ".split("[\\s,]+")` returns a `String[]` of length 4 - not 3 as expected.

Comment: you have to add -1 as limit to the split("regex",limit)-Method, otherwise the empty cells at the end get truncated see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-

Comment: CSV can contain a comma within a quote. Example: `foo,"bar,baz",qux`. See this answer for a good regex in such situations: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1757107/1048340

Comment: `"[\\s,]+"` will also split on internal space within a comma separated token, it will treat both whitespace as a delimiter even when a comma is not present, instead of a comma plus any number of surrounding whitespace. `"\\s*(,\\s*)+"` will trim whitespace only around comma separated tokens, and also ignore any strings that are only whitespace or empty.

Comment: As a side note: if you expect to get an empty list in case of an empty input string, then this method does not suit your use case. You will get a list with 1 element containing an empty string.

Comment: @MadisPukkonen, you are absolutely right, but I respect the OP enough to assume that he can add such logic himself.

Comment: @AlexR Although I appreciate that you respect the OP, but, I would refrain from saying such things. I know of people that feel bad for not meeting people's expectations when praised falsely. Just a thought.

Comment: @theferrit32 your statement is not true, since strings like ", whatever" will put an empty string as the first member of the collection.

Answer (score 241):

`Arrays.asList` returns a fixed-size `List` backed by the array. If you want a normal mutable `java.util.ArrayList` you need to do this:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(string.split(" , ")));
```

Or, using [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com):

```
List<String> list = Lists.newArrayList(Splitter.on(" , ").split(string));
```

Using a `Splitter` gives you more flexibility in how you split the string and gives you the ability to, for example, skip empty strings in the results and trim results. It also has less weird behavior than `String.split` as well as not requiring you to split by regex (that's just one option).

Comment: Would have preferred **Splitter.on(",").trimResults().split(string)** although I see you did mention it. so +1

Comment: +1 for pointing out that Arrays.asList doesn't return a normal list. If you try to add or remove an element to/from that List you will get an UnsupportedOperationException.

Comment: Guava now has this since (15.0) : **Splitter.on(",").splitToList(string)**.  Saves a small step.

Comment: Is there any way to also add empty values in String iike if I've String like this: 1,,3,4,5 here 2 is missing/empty. When converting in list 2 will skip. But I want to add this as empty value.

Comment: The problem with this implementation, and some other similar examples, is that although the `Arrays.asList` provides a wrapper around the native array (avoiding an element copy), the `new ArrayList(...)` will exactly do such an element by element copy. We should probably prefer an approach that allows parsed elements to be directly added to the desired target collection.

Comment: This one is the right answer. you can try on the online java compiler.
https://www.compilejava.net/

Answer (score 85):

Two steps:

1. `String [] items = commaSeparated.split("\\s*,\\s*");`
2. `List<String> container = Arrays.asList(items);`

Comment: Once you inline the items variable, it is basically the same as other answers, but a bit more efficient actually since it doesn't use regex.  On the flip side, spaces around the comma will kill this option.

Comment: @AmrinderArora the argument to `split` is interpreted as a RegEx.

Answer (score 70):

```
List<String> items= Stream.of(commaSeparated.split(","))
     .map(String::trim)
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: One of the best answer now. List can be altered in this answer +1.

Comment: works after changed `collect(toList())` to `collect(Collectors.toList()`

Comment: In fact `collect(toList())` is using the static import of  `Collectors.toList()` for brevity and fluency :)

Comment: it's amazing because it covers the case of empty string and single string without separator.

Comment: If you have a string like ", whatever, " it will ad two empty string member to the list, one at the beginning and another one at the end.

Comment: If you want to get rid of empty string, just add a filter() like `.filter(str -> !str.isEmpty())`  after `.map()` :)

Comment: List<String> items= Stream.of(commaSeparated.split(","))
     .map(String::trim)
     .filter(StringUtils.isNotBlank())
     .collect(Collectors.toList());

Answer (score 27):

If a `List` is the end-goal as the OP stated, then already accepted answer is still the shortest and the best. However I want to provide alternatives using [Java 8 Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html), that will give you more benefit if it is part of a pipeline for further processing.

By wrapping the result of the .split function (a native array) into a stream and then converting to a list.

```
List<String> list =
  Stream.of("a,b,c".split(","))
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If it is important that the result is stored as an `ArrayList` as per the title from the OP, you can use a different `Collector` method:

```
ArrayList<String> list = 
  Stream.of("a,b,c".split(","))
  .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList<String>::new));
```

Or by using the RegEx parsing api:

```
ArrayList<String> list = 
  Pattern.compile(",")
  .splitAsStream("a,b,c")
  .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList<String>::new));
```

Note that you could still consider to leave the `list` variable typed as `List<String>` instead of `ArrayList<String>`. The generic interface for `List` still looks plenty of similar enough to the `ArrayList` implementation.

By themselves, these code examples do not seem to add a lot (except more typing), but if you are planning to do more, like [this answer on converting a String to a List of Longs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27503359/744133) exemplifies, the streaming API is really powerful by allowing to pipeline your operations one after the other.

For the sake of, you know, completeness.

Answer (score 24):

Here is another one for converting  CSV to ArrayList:

```
String str="string,with,comma";
ArrayList aList= new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(str.split(",")));
for(int i=0;i<aList.size();i++)
{
    System.out.println(" -->"+aList.get(i));
}
```

Prints you

> -->string
>       -->with
>       -->comma

Answer (score 18):

```
List<String> items = Arrays.asList(commaSeparated.split(","));
```

That should work for you.

Answer (score 16):

There is no built-in method for this but you can simply use split() method in this.

```
String commaSeparated = "item1 , item2 , item3";
ArrayList<String> items = 
new  ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(commaSeparated.split(",")));
```

Answer (score 10):

you can combine asList and split

```
Arrays.asList(CommaSeparated.split("\\s*,\\s*"))
```

Answer (score 10):

This code will help,

```
String myStr = "item1,item2,item3";
List myList = Arrays.asList(myStr.split(","));
```

Comment: Hoped this would work in `groovy` but didn't :(

Answer (score 8):

You can use Guava to split the string, and convert it into an ArrayList. This works with an empty string as well, and returns an empty list.

```
import com.google.common.base.Splitter;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

String commaSeparated = "item1 , item2 , item3";

// Split string into list, trimming each item and removing empty items
ArrayList<String> list = Lists.newArrayList(Splitter.on(',').trimResults().omitEmptyStrings().splitToList(commaSeparated));
System.out.println(list);

list.add("another item");
System.out.println(list);
```

outputs the following:

```
[item1, item2, item3]
[item1, item2, item3, another item]
```

You could also use the following approach without Guava:

```
  public static List<String> getStringAsList(String input) {
    if (input == null || input.trim().length() == 0) {
      return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    final String separators = "[;:,-]";
    var result =
        Splitter.on(CharMatcher.anyOf(separators))
            .trimResults()
            .omitEmptyStrings()
            .splitToList(input);

    return result;
  }
```

Answer (score 7):

Java 9 introduced List.of():

```
String commaSeparated = "item1 , item2 , item3";
List<String> items = List.of(commaSeparated.split(" , "));
```

Comment: This is not working if you want to include an empty item if the String ends with a comma.

Answer (score 5):

There are many ways to solve this using streams in **Java 8** but IMO the following one liners are straight forward:

```
String  commaSeparated = "item1 , item2 , item3";
List<String> result1 = Arrays.stream(commaSeparated.split(" , "))
                                             .collect(Collectors.toList());
List<String> result2 = Stream.of(commaSeparated.split(" , "))
                                             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Does anyone know how can i convert this String to comma seperated list --String s = "2017-07-12 23:40:00.0,153.76,16.140,60.00,,56.00,";
  List<String> splittedString = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(s.split("\\s*,\\s*")));

Comment: This is a new question, do not ask it as a comment. Feel free to create a new question.

Answer (score 4):

In groovy, you can use tokenize(Character Token) method:

```
list = str.tokenize(',')
```

Comment: This one saved me! Thank you.

Comment: Best answer, nice one!

Answer (score 4):

An example using `Collections`.

```
import java.util.Collections;
 ...
String commaSeparated = "item1 , item2 , item3";
ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
Collections.addAll(items, commaSeparated.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
 ...
```

Comment: You avoided the intermediary Arrays.asList. Unfortunately we still have a copy from array elements into the collection. Nice alternative to remember.

Answer (score 2):

You can first split them using `String.split(",")`, and then convert the returned String `array` to an `ArrayList` using `Arrays.asList(array)`

Answer (score 2):

Same result you can achieve using the Splitter class.

```
var list = Splitter.on(",").splitToList(YourStringVariable)
```

(written in kotlin)

Comment: The documentation says this function is beta and unstable.

Answer (score 2):

While this question is old and has been answered multiple times, none of the answers is able to manage the all of the following cases:

- `""` -> empty string should be mapped to empty list
- `" a, b , c "` -> all elements should be trimmed, including the first and last element
- `",,"` -> empty elements should be removed

Thus, I'm using the following code (using `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils`, e.g. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.11):

```
StringUtils.isBlank(commaSeparatedEmailList) ?
            Collections.emptyList() :
            Stream.of(StringUtils.split(commaSeparatedEmailList, ','))
                    .map(String::trim)
                    .filter(StringUtils::isNotBlank)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Using a simple split expression has an advantage: no regular expression is used, so the performance is probably higher. The `commons-lang3` library is lightweight and very common.

Note that the implementation assumes that you don't have list element containing comma (i.e. `"a, 'b,c', d"` will be parsed as `["a", "'b", "c'", "d"]`, not to `["a", "b,c", "d"]`).

Answer (score 2):

In java, It can be done like this

```
String catalogue_id = "A, B, C";
List<String> catalogueIdList = Arrays.asList(catalogue_id.split(", [ ]*"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List commaseperated = new ArrayList();
String mylist = "item1 , item2 , item3";
mylist = Arrays.asList(myStr.trim().split(" , "));

// enter code here
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually use precompiled pattern for the list. And also this is slightly more universal since it can consider brackets which follows some of the listToString expressions.

```
private static final Pattern listAsString = Pattern.compile("^\\[?([^\\[\\]]*)\\]?$");

private List<String> getList(String value) {
  Matcher matcher = listAsString.matcher((String) value);
  if (matcher.matches()) {
    String[] split = matcher.group(matcher.groupCount()).split("\\s*,\\s*");
    return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(split));
  }
  return Collections.emptyList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String> items = Arrays.asList(s.split("[,\\s]+"));
```

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin if your String list like this and you can use for convert string to ArrayList use this line of code

```
var str= "item1, item2, item3, item4"
var itemsList = str.split(", ")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows.

This removes white space and split by comma where you do not need to worry about white spaces.

```
    String myString= "A, B, C, D";

    //Remove whitespace and split by comma 
    List<String> finalString= Arrays.asList(myString.split("\\s*,\\s*"));

    System.out.println(finalString);
```

Answer (score 0):

This method will convert your string to an array, taking two parameters:

- the string you want converted, and
- the characters that will separate the values in the string.

It then returns the converted array.

```
private String[] convertStringToArray(String stringIn, String separators){
    
    // separate string into list depending on separators
    List<String> tempList = Arrays.asList(stringIn.split(separators));
    
    // create a new pre-populated array based on the size of the list
    String[] itemsArray = new String[tempList.size()];
    
    // convert the list to an array
    itemsArray = tempList.toArray(itemsArray);
    
    return itemsArray;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here are two more extended versions of the code that utilize Java 8 streams:

```
List<String> stringList1 = 
    Arrays.stream(commaSeparated.split(","))
      .map(String::trim)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<String> stringList2 = 
    Stream.of(commaSeparated.split(","))
      .map(String::trim)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score -2):

convert Collection into string as comma seperated in **Java 8**

listOfString object contains ["A","B","C" ,"D"] elements-

```
listOfString.stream().map(ele->"'"+ele+"'").collect(Collectors.joining(","))
```

**Output is :-**
'A','B','C','D'

**And Convert Strings Array to List in Java 8**

```
    String string[] ={"A","B","C","D"};
    List<String> listOfString = Stream.of(string).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score -5):

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mListmain = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(); 
String marray[]= mListmain.split(",");
```

Comment: And where exactly is the `ArrayList`? Did you even read the question?

Comment: @mapeters: There was a `ArrayList`. I rolled back the edits to the first revision (so you can see it) and improved the formatting of the first revision.

Comment: Question is how to convert string to ArrayList, not how to convert ArrayList to Array.