# Convert Comma Separated Values to List<Long>

Tags: java

Assume I have a set of numbers like `1,2,3,4,5,6,7` input as a single `String`. I would like to convert those numbers to a `List` of `Long` objects ie `List<Long>`.

Can anyone recommend the easiest method?

Answer (score -14, accepted):

I would use the excellent google's Guava library to do it. String.split can cause many troubles.

```
String numbers="1,2,3,4,5,6,7";
Iterable<String> splitIterator = Splitter.on(',').split(numbers);
List<String> list= Lists.newArrayList(splitIterator );
```

Comment: Do not use standard Java (hence not the easiest method), neither solve the problem.

Comment: Either this answer is not right or @Kathir question is not right.

Comment: @jocelyn `String.split can cause many troubles.` Such as....?

Comment: @DorianGray: https://errorprone.info/bugpattern/StringSplitter

Answer (score 68):

You mean something like this?

```
String numbers = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7";

List<Long> list = new ArrayList<Long>();
for (String s : numbers.split(","))
    list.add(Long.parseLong(s));

System.out.println(list);
```

Since Java 8 you can rewrite it as

```
List<Long> list = Stream.of(numbers.split(","))
        .map(Long::parseLong)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

Little shorter versions if you want to get `List<String>`

```
List<String> fixedSizeList = Arrays.asList(numbers.split(","));
List<String> resizableList = new ArrayList<>(fixedSizeList);
```

or one-liner

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(numbers.split(",")));
```

---

Bonus info:

If your data may be in form like `String data = "1, 2 , 3,4";` where comma is surrounded by some whitespaces, the `split(",")` will produce as result array like `["1", " 2 ", " 3", "4"]`.

As you see second and third element in that array contains those extra spaces: `" 2 "`, `" 3"` which would cause `Long.parseLong` to throw `NumberFormatException` (since space is not proper numerical value).

Solution here is either:

- using `String#trim` on those individual elements before parsing like `Long.parseLong(s.trim())`
- *consuming* those extra whitespace along `,` while splitting. To do that we can use `split("\\s*,\\s*")` where

  - `\s` (written as `"\\s"` in string literals) represents whitespace
  - `*` is quantifier representing *zero or more*
    so `"\\s*"` represents zero or more whitespaces (in other words makes it optional)

Comment: This answer is super old, but still relevant and should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Adding one slight change,
`String numbers = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7";
List<Long> list = new ArrayList<Long>();
for (String s : numbers.split(","))
    list.add(Long.parseLong(s.trim()));
System.out.println(list);`

Added _s.trim()_ so that if there is a string like, "1, 2", it does not throw a `NumberFormatException` for string " 2".

Comment: @VickySingh Alternative since `split` supports *regex* we can use `split("\\s*,\\s*)` instead of `split(",")` to split on *comma with possible whitespaces surrounding it*.

Answer (score 12):

Simple and handy solution using [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) (for the sake of completion of the thread):

```
String str = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7";
List<Long> list = Arrays.stream(str.split(",")).map(Long::parseLong).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

> ```
> System.out.println(list);
> ```
>
> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

Even better, using `Pattern.splitAsStream()`:

```
Pattern.compile(",").splitAsStream(str).map(Long::parseLong).collect(Collectors‌​.toList());
```

Answer (score 3):

```
String input = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7";
String[] numbers = input.split("\\,");
List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(String number : numbers) {
    try {
        result.add(Integer.parseInt(number.trim()));
    } catch(Exception e) {
        // log about conversion error
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there is any utility method availalble in java or apache commons or any other to get the results in a simple way by calling a method?

Comment: You can use some appache or guava collections based on visitor pattern to convert String to Integer, but it will not make code simple. It will make it is harder to read.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `String.split()` and `Long.valueOf()`:

```
String numbers = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7";
List<Long> list = new ArrayList<Long>();
for (String s : numbers.split(","))
    list.add(Long.valueOf(s));

System.out.println(list);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're not on java8 and don't want to use loops, then you can use [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)

```java
List<Long> longValues = Lists.transform(Arrays.asList(numbersArray.split(",")), new Function<String, Long>() {
                @Override
                public Long apply(String input) {
                    return Long.parseLong(input.trim());
                }
            });
```

As others have mentioned for Java8 you can use Streams.

```java
List<Long> numbers = Arrays.asList(numbersArray.split(","))
                      .stream()
                      .map(String::trim)
                      .map(Long::parseLong)
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Instead of `Arrays.asList(numbersArray.split(",")).stream()`, simply `Arrays.stream(numbersArray.split(","))` or `Stream.of(numbersArray.split(","))` can be used.

Comment: @UtkuÖzdemir actually cant. In that case Lists.transform cannot be used to convert the String to Long.

Comment: I mean the java8 solution, not the guava one.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the following recently:

```
import static com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.toImmutableList;
import com.google.common.base.Splitter;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;
...

    final ImmutableList<Long> result = Splitter.on(",")
        .trimResults()
        .omitEmptyStrings()
        .splitToStream(value)
        .map(Long::valueOf)
        .collect(toImmutableList());
```

This uses Splitter from Guava (to handle empty strings and whitespaces) and does
not use the [surprising String.split()](https://errorprone.info/bugpattern/StringSplitter).