# How do I break out a delimited String to a List<String>

Tags: java, string, split

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: How to convert comma separated String to ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488643/java-how-to-convert-comma-separated-string-to-arraylist)

I have a the String `Red*Blue*Yellow*Green*White`. How do I break that String out by `*` into a `List<String>`?

Comment: There must be hundreds of questions on this topic here on SO, please search before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this: -

```
String str = "Red*Blue*Yellow*Green";
String[] arr = str.split("\\*");
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(arr));
```

**NOTE**:-

**`Arrays.asList`** returns you an `unmodifiable` list, so if you want a `modifiable list`, you need to create a new list by using the `constructor of ArrayList`, that takes a `Collection` object as parameter.

Also, since `*` is a special character in `Regex`, and `String.split()` takes a `Regex` for splitting. So, you need to escape the `*` with a backslash.

**OUTPUT**: -

```
[Red, Blue, Yellow, Green]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  String[] str ="Red*Blue*Yellow*Green*White".split("\\*");
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(str);
```

Output:

```
[Red, Blue, Yellow, Green, White]
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
       String ss="Red*Blue*Yellow*Green*Whit";
       String sss[] = ss.split("\\*");
       List <String> ssss = Arrays.asList(sss);
```

Comment: You need to escape that `*` with \\.