# Using delimiter when reading a file

Tags: java, delimiter

I have little experience using delimiters and i need to read a text file that stores several objects whose data is stored in single lines separate by commas (","). The seperate strings are then used to create a new object which is added to an arraylist.

```
Amadeus,Drama,160 Mins.,1984,14.83
As Good As It Gets,Drama,139 Mins.,1998,11.3
Batman,Action,126 Mins.,1989,10.15
Billy Elliot,Drama,111 Mins.,2001,10.23
Blade Runner,Science Fiction,117 Mins.,1982,11.98
Shadowlands,Drama,133 Mins.,1993,9.89
Shrek,Animation,93 Mins,2001,15.99
Snatch,Action,103 Mins,2001,20.67
The Lord of the Rings,Fantasy,178 Mins,2001,25.87
```

I am using Scanner to read the file, however i get a no line found error and the entire file is stored into one string:

```
Scanner read = new Scanner (new File("datafile.txt"));
read.useDelimiter(",");
String title, category, runningTime, year, price;

while (read.hasNext())
{
   title = read.nextLine();
   category = read.nextLine();
   runningTime = read.nextLine();
   year = read.nextLine();
   price = read.nextLine();
   System.out.println(title + " " + category + " " + runningTime + " " +
                      year + " " + price + "\n"); // just for debugging
}
read.close();
```

Comment: use `read.next()` instead of `nextLine()`.

Answer (score 12):

Use read.next() instead of read.nextLine()

```
   title = read.next();
   category = read.next();
   runningTime = read.next();
   year = read.next();
   price = read.next();
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you want to call `.next()` which returns a String instead of `.nextLine()`. Your `.nextLine()` call is moving past the current line.

```
Scanner read = new Scanner (new File("datafile.txt"));
   read.useDelimiter(",");
   String title, category, runningTime, year, price;

   while(read.hasNext())
   {
       title = read.next();
       category = read.next();
       runningTime = read.next();
       year = read.next();
       price = read.next();
     System.out.println(title + " " + category + " " + runningTime + " " + year + " " + price + "\n"); //just for debugging
   }
   read.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `next();`  where you are using `nextLine();`

Have a look at the tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html

Notice the lines:

```
try {
   s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("xanadu.txt")));

   while (s.hasNext()) {
   System.out.println(s.next());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

All of the answers above are right and actually the same. However, one important point everybody should remember that the `Scanner` has a buffer size of only 1024. That means if the length of the delimited text is more, the parsing will stop.

So, a little enhancement to the given solution, use `BufferedReader` instead of directly passing the file to the `Scanner`. Example:

```
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("datafile.txt"), 16*1024);
    Scanner read = new Scanner(in);
    read.useDelimiter(",");
    String title, category, runningTime, year, price;

    while(read.hasNext())
    {
        title = read.next();
        category = read.next();
        runningTime = read.next();
        year = read.next();
        price = read.next();
        System.out.println(title + " " + category + " " + runningTime + " " + year + " " + price + "\n"); //just for debugging
    }
    read.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a String.split() function to convert the string to an array of strings, then iterate over each of them for your values.

[How to convert comma-separated String to ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488643/java-how-to-convert-comma-separated-string-to-arraylist) see this for more details.

Answer (score 0):

One issue is:

```
while(read.hasNext())
   {
       title = read.nextLine();
       category = read.nextLine();
       runningTime = read.nextLine();

hasNext()
```

Returns true if this scanner has another token in its input. Not entire line. You need to use [hasNextLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine%28%29)

You are doing nextLine() three times. I think what you need to do is, read the line and the split the line.