# java - read file terminated by unicode character

Tags: java, file-io, java-8

I have a special file where the lines are terminated by  `'\001'`.

I want to read this file line by line.
I have been using `Files.lines(path)`. but this fails now, since the lines are not terminated by new line character.

what is the best way to do?

Comment: Read whole file as a string, and using [`StringTokenizer`](https://www.javatpoint.com/string-tokenizer-in-java) with `\001` as delimiter to split line by line. Or you can using `String.split` function to split it into an array then read one by one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it has '\001' instead of newline chars, you can read the whole file and split the string at the '\001' using [split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-).

Alternatively, you can use [delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14242984/using-delimiter-when-reading-a-file)