# How to create an ArrayList that I can add items too like this Java

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have the following String list which is constructed as:

```
String[] messageList = messages.split("(?<=\\G.{" + 9 + "})");
```

I want to be able to add new strings to the list but of course this would need to be an arraylist.

How could I make an array list from this string list?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: How to convert comma separated String to ArrayList](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488643/java-how-to-convert-comma-separated-string-to-arraylist)

Answer (score 3):

Use [Arrays#asList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29). Try,

```
List<String> list= new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(messageList));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Arrays.#asList(T...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) to construct a new `ArrayList` containing the elements in the `messageList` array.

Before Java 7 :

```
List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(messageList));
```

After :

```
List<String> l = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(messageList));
```

Or directly :

```
List<String> l = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(messages.split("(?<=\\G.{" + 9 + "})")));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
List<String> lst = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(messageList));
```

or:

```
List<String> lst = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(message.split("(?<=\\G.{" + 9 + "})")));
```

Also check [Arrays.asList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29)

> Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array. (Changes to
>   the returned list "write through" to the array.) This method acts as
>   bridge between array-based and collection-based APIs, in combination
>   with Collection.toArray(). The returned list is serializable and
>   implements RandomAccess.

Answer (score 2):

```
List<String> lst = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(messages.split("(?<=\\G.{" + 9 + "})")));
```