# How to split a comma-delimited string into an array of empty strings

Tags: java, string, split

I want to split `",,,"` to a array of 4 `""` using the `String.split()`

Here is my code:

```
String str = ",,,";     
String[] tokens = str.split(",");
```

However, the result tokens were an an empty array: [], rather than an array of 4 `""` `(["","","",""])` as I wanted.

I have tested to change the `str` a little bit:

```
String str = ",,,1";        
String[] tokens = str.split(",");
```

This time the result tokens were `["","","","1"]`. This is close to what I want, but I really do not  want to add this "1" before doing the split.

The problem is basically, the `String.split()` will return an empty array if it contains only empty elements `""`.

Can you help solve the problem?

Comment: If you were using Guava, `Splitter.on(",").split(",,,")` produces the expected result. See e.g. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7488710/56285) for more.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need to use the overloaded [`String#split(regex, limit)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)) method which takes in the limit parameter.

```
String[] tokens = str.split(",", -1);
```

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int))(emphasis mine):

> The limit parameter controls the number of times the pattern is applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array. If the limit n is greater than zero then the pattern will be applied at most n - 1 times, the array's length will be no greater than n, and the array's last entry will contain all input beyond the last matched delimiter. **If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible and the array can have any length.** If n is zero then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array can have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded.

---

**Explanation:** When you do not provide the limit argument or provide "zero" as the limit, the `split()` discards trailing empty fields. When you provide a positive limit argument, it limits the number of fields to that particular limit. But when you provide a negative limit, the `split()` method allows any number of fields and also not discarding the trailing empty fields. To be more clear, have a look at the source code of the [`Pattern#split(regex, limit)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/regex/Pattern.java#Pattern.split%28java.lang.CharSequence%2Cint%29) which has this snippet at the end(comments have been added by me and were not present in the actual source code).

```
if (limit == 0) // When zero or no arg is given
    while (resultSize > 0 && matchList.get(resultSize-1).equals("")) // if trailing entries are blank
        resultSize--; // remove them out
```

*Note:* If you do not provide any limit argument, the `split()` method without limit argument calls the overloaded `split()` method [like this](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.split%28java.lang.String%29).

```
public String[] split(String regex) {
    return split(regex, 0);
}
```

And also note that, [`String#split(regex, limit)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.split%28java.lang.String%2Cint%29) internally calls the [`Pattern#split(regex, limit)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/regex/Pattern.java#Pattern.split%28java.lang.CharSequence%2Cint%29).

Comment: Care to explain this for the above example? If I'm not asking for too much.

Comment: What does it mean by "applied as many times as possible"? How does that give us an array of empty strings?

Comment: AnjanBaradwaj, @GIJoe - I've updated the answer with a little more explanation and the source code.