# String#split. Side effect of limit parameter

Tags: java, string, split

There are in JDK  exist following split overloading signature

```
public String[] split(String regex, int limit)
```

Always I suppose that limit is the maximum number of tokens the string will be split.

for example:

### first snippet:

```
 System.out.println(Arrays.toString("Andrew Carnegie:35:USA".split(":")));
```

out:

```
[Andrew Carnegie, 35, USA]
```

### second snippet:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("Andrew Carnegie:35:USA".split(":",2)));
```

out

```
[Andrew Carnegie, 35:USA]
```

But I noticed 1 more effect

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("Andrew Carnegie:35:USA:".split(":")));
```

out:

```
[Andrew Carnegie, 35, USA]
```

and

```
 System.out.println(Arrays.toString("Andrew Carnegie:35:USA:".split(":",-1)));
```

out:

```
[Andrew Carnegie, 35, USA, ]
```

Thus added an empty element if string ends by delimiter.

Where can I find specific information about this effect?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[java]%20split%20empty

Comment: [Have a look at my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22350715/2024761). I've explained the effect along with some source code snippet :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java split() method strips empty strings at the end?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/545957/java-split-method-strips-empty-strings-at-the-end)

Comment: In Java 8 this mechanism also affects empty strings at start of result array if split was done on zero-width match. More info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22718744/why-does-split-in-jdk-8-sometimes-removes-empty-strings-if-they-are-at-start-of).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Citing *Johannes Weiß*:

"When calling String.split(String), it calls String.split(String, 0) and that discards trailing empty strings (as the docs say it), when calling String.split(String, n) with n < 0 it won't discard anything."

Answer (score 0):

From the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) for `split`:

> The limit parameter controls the number of times the pattern is
>   applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array. If
>   the limit n is greater than zero then the pattern will be applied at
>   most n - 1 times, the array's length will be no greater than n, and
>   the array's last entry will contain all input beyond the last matched
>   delimiter. **If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as
>   many times as possible and the array can have any length**. If n is zero
>   then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array
>   can have any length, and **trailing empty strings will be discarded**.

Emphasis mine.

So,

- if `n` is strictly positive then the number of elements in the resulting array will be limited by `n`
- if `n` is zero then the array can have any length and trailing spaces will be discarded
- if `n` is strictly negative then the array can have any length and trailing spaces will not be discarded