# How do I sepzrate by commas and newline?

Tags: java

How does one convert something like this (assuming I'm using a Buffered Reader to read in the info?):

```
0, blah, hi\n
1, bluh, test
```

To this:

```
String[] testArray:
0, blah, hi, 1, bluh, test
```

If that makes any sense? Basically removing the commas and newlines and inserting each different word into its own element.

Comment: Why the 1 after the 0?

Comment: @MauricePerry Oops, typo.

Comment: What did you try so far? A basic way would be to read everything into a single string and then split by newlines and commas (hint: the `String` class has methods for this).

Comment: Yes , it is possible... but you have to define the merging order. .in the example you post makes not much sense

Comment: Just read each line, split on the coma and concat each resulting array (using a list will be simpler). I let you write the code

Comment: Did you even search online? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22350683/how-to-split-a-comma-delimited-string-into-an-array-of-empty-strings  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488643/how-to-convert-comma-separated-string-to-arraylist     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631715/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-string

Answer (score 0):

A naive implementation:

```
List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<>();
for (String line = in.readLine(); line != null; line = in.readLine()) {
    for (String token: line.split(",\\s*")) {
        tokens.add(token);
    }
}
String[] testArray = tokens.toArray(new String[tokens.size()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier to do such things with a [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) with a custom delimiter than reinventing the wheel, IMHO:

```
String str = "0, blah, hi\n1, bluh, test";
Reader reader = new StringReader(str); // Just an example, any Reader would work
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(reader).useDelimiter(", ");
List<String> tmpList = new LinkedList<>();
scanner.forEachRemaining(tmpList::add);
String[] array = tmpList.toArray(new String[tmpList.size()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer for Java 8.

```
String[] array = Files.newBufferedReader(PATH_OF_THE_FILE)
    .lines()
    .flatMap(string -> java.util.stream.Stream.of(string.split(",\\s")))
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
    .toArray(new String[0]);
```