# Conversion from printed ArrayList to ArrayList object

Tags: java, arraylist

I have the printed value of an ArrayList of Strings.

`[a, b, c, d]`

This will be in String format.

Eg.

`String temp = "[a, b, c, d]"`

How can I convert this into an ArrayList of String object?

Comment: What did you try? Please show your code.

Comment: why you have [] ? can you tell me what it means here?

Comment: your question is confusing.

Comment: I have the printed value of an ArrayList<String> : If the ArrayList = {"a", "b", "c", "d"}, it gets printed as [a, b, c, d].           With this printed list, I want to convert to an ArrayList<String>.     So my input is a String temp = "[a, b, c, d]", how can I convert to an ArrayList?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488643/java-how-to-convert-comma-separated-string-to-arraylist

Comment: because it stores the values as the **Objects** . so what do you expect here ?

Comment: @BetaRide: I could hard code the conversion, by splitting with a comma, and reading each element and adding it to the list, I was wondering if a conversion method from String(That represents the sys out value of an ArrayList) to an ArrayList exists

Comment: Yes you can, substring from 1 to n-2 ( remove two braces) and split by comma

Comment: @TejasPatel: any in-built functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple code

```
String temp = "[a, b, c, d]";

// trim enclosing brackets and then split by comma and space
String[] array = temp.substring(1, temp.length() - 1).split(", ");

List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

for (String s : array) {
    list.add(s);
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming there aren't any in-built functions to do this

Comment: Sorry There are infinite no of problems in the JAVA world :)

Comment: Could you also help me in one thing, similarly, if I have contents of a Stack in a String, and want to reconvert to an Object of Stack type, how could I do that? I would have to read the string in a reverse order?

Comment: Where is the issue? Just code and code to make you perfect. Try to experiment on code. It's very easy.