# how to split array list values by comma and show that spitted values in list view?

Tags: android, string, arraylist, split

I was store some values as a comma separated string in Sq lite database. Now i want to getting that values from database to list view.  But problem is, the comma separated string is directly visible in list view, i want to split that string and display  in list view. I am very confusing because, i used array list to get comma separated from DB,  I don't know how to split that string in array list and display list view?

```
 how to split string from Arraylist by comma and get that stringd to listview.
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488643/java-how-to-convert-comma-separated-string-to-arraylist

Comment: thank you, i did what you told.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String temp = arrayValues.toString());
String qusChoice = temp.substring(1,temp.length() - 1);
String[] arrayList = qusChoice.split(",");
ArrayList choiceList = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.length; i++) {

         choiceList.add(arrayList[i]);
    }

    ListView listChoice = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_choice);
    adapter = new ChoiceAdapter(MainActivity.this,R.layout.custom_list,choiceList );
    listChoice.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: thank you rajesh, here i want to display this splitted strings into inflated xml file text view. means if the splitted strings are two, then first string display in first row textview, second string will display in second row textview. give me an idea

Comment: if i value is odd number assign first row text view and i values is even means assign second row text view. may be it will help you