# Comma separated String to ListProperty

Tags: java, javafx, listproperty

I must write method, which will get my string(showing hours separated with commas), and return ListProperty of Strings.
In my constructor I have

```
this.showingHour = new SimpleListProperty<String>();
```

I wanted to use method from this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7488676/4750111

```
List<String> items = Arrays.asList(str.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
```

But it will create ArrayList. Is there function like this, but for ListProperty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
    ListProperty<String> list = new SimpleListProperty<(
        FXCollections.observableArrayList(str.split("\\s*,\\s*")));
```

As an aside, do you really need a `ListProperty`? I've never found a use for it; I find just using a regular `ObservableList` and registering listeners with it is enough. The arguments to `SimpleListProperty` above, i.e.

```
FXCollections.observableArrayList(str.split("\\s*,\\s*"))
```

gives you an observable list with the elements you need.

Comment: Thanks, I had to change declaration to `this.showingHour = new SimpleListProperty<String>(FXCollections.observableList(new ArrayList<String>()));` and then do the split

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
ListProperty<String> lp= new ListProperty<>();

lp.addAll(Arrays.asList(str.split("\\s*,\\s*")));
```

Comment: From which line - adding or creating?

Comment: Adding. I'm getting String to split from other method by "getText"

Comment: I see you have SimpleListProperty class. How it is declared? `class SimpleListProperty ` and then what? `extends` , `implements`? Paste whole line here.

Comment: SimpleListProperty is declaration of this List, like other variables like SimpleStringProperty and SimpleIntegerProperty. It's all in one class Movie, where i just import javafx.beans.property.ListProperty and javafx.beans.property.SimpleListProperty