# Convert comma-separated string to list of variables?

Tags: java, string, split

For Java and in reference to this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488643/how-to-convert-comma-separated-string-to-arraylist) how could I save each value in this array to a separate variable?

If string value is:

```
1234,AAA,30
```

Variables would be:

```
var1=1234
var2=AAA
var3=30
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I'm not sure if that's possible.

Comment: Split the string using the .split() method. Then you have an Array where you can iterate over and fill for example a Map<String, String>

Comment: Did you understand the answer?

Comment: @ItamarGreen I think it is clear enough, I am trying it right-now.

Comment: @Eng7 did you try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
String str = "1234,AAA,30";
String[] variables = str.split(",");
String first = variables[0];
String second = variables[1];
String third = variables[2];
```

and that should work

Answer (score 2):

You can use this in a for loop

```
String s = "012,345AA,89";
String[] output = s.split(",");
System.out.println(output[0]);
System.out.println(output[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this if the array size is not fixed

```
    String str = "1234,AAA,30";
    String[] arr = str.split(",");
    Map<Object, Object> map = IntStream.range(0, arr.length).boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(in -> "var" + (in + 1), in -> arr[in], (k, v) -> v, LinkedHashMap::new));
    System.out.println(map);
```

output

```
{var1=1234, var2=AAA, var3=30}
```