# I have a arraylist and i want to split the arraylist with delimiter ',' and show the data in table format in jsp using jstl

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist, jsp-tags

My arraylist contains the following details
arraylist.get(0) will be like "name,age,place,address,city"
Likewise I have many entries in the arraylist.

Expected output: table
Name Age Place Address City

Comment: Do you mean this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488643/how-to-convert-comma-separated-string-to-arraylist ??

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like this to split it with the comma and then join it with the spaces using `StringUtils`,

```
import com.sun.deploy.util.StringUtils;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String value = "name,age,place,address,city";
        String result = StringUtils.join(Arrays.asList(value.split(",")), " ");
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```