# Split Stream of Lines to extract comma seperated data

Tags: java, java-stream

Each line in the file has comma seperated data.I need to extract each field based on comma from each row as String and store as property. How to achieve that using Java Streams?

```
Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(wiki_path);
```

Comment: This post also has some interesting info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488643/how-to-convert-comma-separated-string-to-arraylist

Answer (score 2):

**Read from the file:**

`Files::lines` returns a sequence of lines `Stream<String>` which might be used for your advantage.

```
List<String> propertyList = Files.lines(wiki_path)    // Stream<String>      
        .map(line ->line.split(";"))                  // Stream<String[]>
        .flatMap(Arrays::stream)                      // Stream<String>
        .collect(Collectors.toList());                // List<String>
```

The result is a `List` of all the properties read from the file separated with a new line and the `;` delimiter.

---

**Write to Properties**:

Since the properties are built on the key-value principle, you need the key for each loaded property. Let's suppose the value = key:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
propertyList.forEach(property -> properties.set(property, property ));
```

This is rather a very primitive example and you have to amend it to your needs. Read more about properties at [Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html).