# Splitting a String after every whitespace and put into a 2Dimensional List in Java

Tags: java, string, list

i have a a list of Strings such as:
["T Info1 Info2 Info3 Info4", "R Info1 Info2 Info3 Info4"] and so on..

I want to convert this list into a 2 dimensional list to look like:
[ ["T","Info1","Info2"], ["R","Info1","Info2"] ]

Hows the proper coding for it?

appreciate any help!

Comment: Where are you stuck? Don't know how to [split a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488643/how-to-convert-comma-separated-string-to-list)? Or how to create a `List`? Please clarify

Answer (score 1):

You can stream over the list and split each array into another list:

```java
final var list = List.of("T Info1 Info2 Info3 Info4", "R Info1 Info2 Info3 Info4");
final var list2d = list.stream()
        .map(str -> Arrays.asList(str.split(" ")))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(list2d);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution that does not use the [stream API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/architect-streams-pt2.html).

```java
public class Splitter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] source = {"T Info1 Info2 Info3 Info4","R Info1 Info2 Info3 Info4"};
        String[][] result = new String[source.length][];
        for (int i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
            result[i] = source[i].split(" ");
        }
        System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.deepToString(result));
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
[[T, Info1, Info2, Info3, Info4], [R, Info1, Info2, Info3, Info4]]
```