# Java delimited string split help: using regex or anthing else

Tags: java

I'm having a string which is delimited by comma such as:

1. if the value is an integer then comma integer value comma (ex: `,10,`)
2. if the value is a date/string then comma double cotes string/date double cotes comma (ex: `,"myStringValue",`)

The issue is at some point some where i'm expecting to find a string using the above logic i may have anoter comma e.g: comma double cotes string comma string double cotes comma. (ex: `,"myStringValue, withCommaIssue",`)

Is there any way i can still split my inital string? Can I use a regex and the logic for it to be comma followed by double (`,"`) cotes and the end of the string to be signaled only by double cotes comma (`",`)? But for this case will the other substrings which are integers still work?

example:

```
1,20,20,,,"string to be parsed as string","01-jan-2020",,"string having an issue, maybe two",,,
```

In the example above I am able to split the string just fine in substring just that my issue is with the element at position 9 out of 12 possible elements (`"string having an issue, maybe two"`). Also all integer values are not having double cotes and the elements with no value are present as well.

Many thanks,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dealing with commas in a CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769621/dealing-with-commas-in-a-csv-file)

Comment: your question would be way clearer with actual examples instead of text

Comment: First duplicate was not in Java, see those: [How to handle commas in the data of a csv in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15979688/how-to-handle-commas-in-the-data-of-a-csv-in-java) and [Splitting a csv file with quotes as text-delimiter using String.split()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738918/splitting-a-csv-file-with-quotes-as-text-delimiter-using-string-split/15905916#15905916)

Comment: Are you working with properly formatted CSV files? Assuming this is a question from real project (not a college exercise or something), consider using one of the libraries that are built for this purpose. Example: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/ http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @MarkBramnik: yes, they are porperly formatted CSV files. The file is already opened and each line is parsed. I am using an Java based ETL tool which has many Java features but also restrictions. I am at the point in which I can parse 90% of the data, but there are cases in which a comma was entered in the string which for me represents someting different from the business perspective.