# How to read commas in the column of a csv in Java

Tags: java, opencsv, csvreader

I have the following code to read from CSV file in java. It works fine except for the case when I have commas in my column values. I got the exception.

**code:**

```
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(fileReader);
String[] headers = csvReader.readNext();
List<String[]> rows = csvReader.readAll();
```

**Exception:**

```
Exception in thread "main" com.opencsv.exceptions.CsvMalformedLineException: Unterminated quoted field at end of CSV line. Beginning of lost text
```

Comment: change the separator of your columns

Comment: The `CSVReader` class *should* be able to handle this.  It is probable that your CSV input is *not correct* and has formatting errors, which causes the error message.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle commas in the data of a csv in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15979688/how-to-handle-commas-in-the-data-of-a-csv-in-java)

Comment: Probably the program that creates the CSV is broken and doesn't [quote properly](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180#section-2). The real solution is to fix that program, not mangle the input before passing it to the csv parser.

Comment: It seams to me, that the quotes of the line aren't correct. It should look like this:
"field","field","field"
If your fields aren't quoted, try it with the quotes. Commas inside will not harm any more.

Comment: Please post the offending line so we do not have to guess. And edit your question which CSVReader you are using.