# parse csv, do not split within single OR double quotes

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I try to parse a csv with java and have the following issue: The second column is a String (which may also contain comma) enclosed in double-quotes, except if the string itself contains a double quote, then the entire string is enclosed with a single quote. e.g.

Lines may lokk like this:

```
someStuff,"hello", someStuff
someStuff,"hello, SO", someStuff
someStuff,'say "hello, world"', someStuff
someStuff,'say "hello, world', someStuff
```

someStuff are placeholders for other elements, which can also include quotes in the same style

I'm looking for a generic way to split the lines at commas UNLESS enclosed in single OR double quotes in order to get the second column as a String. With second column I mean the fields:

- hello
- hello, SO
- say "hello, world"
- say "hello, world

I tried OpenCSV but fail as one can only specifiy one type of quote:

```
public class CSVDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    CSVDemo demo = new CSVDemo();
    demo.process("input.csv");
}

public void process(String fileName) throws IOException {
    String file = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(fileName)
            .getFile();
    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(file));
    String[] nextLine;
    while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
        System.out.println(nextLine[0] + " | " + nextLine[1] + " | "
                + nextLine[2]);
    }
}
```

}

The solution with opencsv fails on the last line where there is only one double quote enclosed in single quotes:

```
someStuff | hello |  someStuff
someStuff | hello, SO |  someStuff
someStuff | 'say "hello, world"' |  someStuff
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
```

Comment: Are you able to change the data? `"say \"hello, world\""` should work in opencsv.

Comment: The data is in a file, so I could change it I guess before parsing... i.e. read line, change/escape quote and then split it

Answer (score 2):

If you truly cannot use a real CSV parser you could use a regex. This is generally not a good idea as there are always edge cases that you cannot handle but if the formatting is strictly as you describe then this may work.

```
public void test() {
    String[] tests = {"numeStuff,\"hello\", someStuff, someStuff",
        "numeStuff,\"hello, SO\", someStuff, someStuff",
        "numeStuff,'say \"hello, world\"', someStuff, someStuff"
    };
    /* Matches a field and a potentially empty separator.
     *
     *  ( - Field Group
     *     \"  - Start with a quote
     *     [^\"]*? - Non-greedy match on anything that is not a quote
     *     \" - End with a quote
     *   | - Or
     *     '  - Start with a strop
     *     [^']*? - Non-greedy match on anything that is not a strop
     *     ' - End with a strop
     *   | - Or
     *    [^\"'] - Not starting with a quote or strop
     *    [^,$]*? - Non-greedy match on anything that is not a comma or end-of-line
     *  ) - End field group
     *  ( - Separator group
     *   [,$] - Comma separator or end of line
     *  ) - End separator group
     */
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\"[^\"]*?\"|'[^\']*?\'|[^\"'][^,\r\n]*?)([,\r\n]|$)");
    for (String t : tests) {
        System.out.println("Matching: " + t);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(t);
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It does not appear that opencsv supports this out of the box. You could extend `com.opencsv.CSVParser` and implement your own algorithm for handling two types of quotes. [This](http://sourceforge.net/p/opencsv/source/ci/master/tree/src/main/java/com/opencsv/CSVParser.java#l327) is the source of the method you would be changing and here is a stub to get you started.

```
class MyCSVParser extends CSVParser{
    @Override
    private String[] parseLine(String nextLine, boolean multi) throws IOException{
        //Your algorithm here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you only need to track `,"` and `,'` (trimming what's in the middle).

When you encounter one of those, set the appropriate flag (eg. singleQuoteOpen, doubleQuoteOpen) to true to indicate they're open and you are in ignore-commas mode.

When you meet the appropriate closing quote, reset the flag and keep slicing the elements.

To perform the check, stop at every comma (when not in ignore-commas mode) and look at the next char (if any, and trimming).

---

Note: the regex solution is good and also shorter, but less customizable for edge cases (at least without big headaches).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem opencv supports this. However, have a look at this previous question and my answer as well as the other answers in case they help
you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15905916/1688441

Below an example, please not `notInsideComma` actually meant "Inside quotes". The following code could be extended to check for both quotes and double quotes.

```
public static ArrayList<String> customSplitSpecific(String s)
{
    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    boolean notInsideComma = true;
    int start =0, end=0;
    for(int i=0; i<s.length()-1; i++)
    {
        if(s.charAt(i)==',' && notInsideComma)
        {
            words.add(s.substring(start,i));
            start = i+1;                
        }   
        else if(s.charAt(i)=='"')
        notInsideComma=!notInsideComma;
    }
    words.add(s.substring(start));
    return words;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the use of single and double quotes is consistent per line, one could chose the corresponding type of quote per line:

```
public class CSVDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        CSVDemo demo = new CSVDemo();
        demo.process("input.csv");
    }

    public void process(String fileName) throws IOException {
        String file = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(fileName)
                .getFile();

        CSVParser doubleParser = new CSVParser(',', '"');
        CSVParser singleParser = new CSVParser(',', '\'');

        String[] nextLine;

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.contains(",'") && line.contains("',")) {
                    nextLine = singleParser.parseLine(line);
                } else {
                    nextLine = doubleParser.parseLine(line);
                }

                System.out.println(nextLine[0] + " | " + nextLine[1] + " | "
                        + nextLine[2]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```