# how to remove commas between the String in the csv file using java

Tags: java, csv

My CSV file look like this

```
"Gates Nissan of Richmond" , "L2T Media, Llc" , "7000000", "--"
```

I want to remove comma(,) from this `"L2T Media, Llc"` in CSV

so that, my output will be `"L2T Media Llc"`

How can I do this in Java coding?

Comment: by writing code that does so. replaceAll comes to mind. Or, write your own algorithm, using the split method

Comment: You can try splitting using quotes instead of commas.

Comment: i just need to remove the comma inside double quotes in the csv file. thats it

Comment: May I ask why you want to remove the comma? - I just ask because it is a completely *well-formed* CSV line to me. And I get the idea that eliminating the comma is just a workaround for not fixing the CSV parsing in the consuming software.

Comment: use split method and spilt using double quotes 
eg. String[] stringList = strTest.split("\",");

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
String str = "\"Gates Nissan of Richmond\" , \"L2T Media, Llc\" , \"7000000\", \"--\"";
List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
for(String item : Arrays.asList(str.substring(1, str.length()-1).split("\"+\\s*,\\s*\"+")))
    items.add("\"" + item.replace(",", "") + "\"");

System.out.println(items);
```

**Output:**

```
["Gates Nissan of Richmond", "L2T Media Llc", "7000000", "--"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738918/splitting-a-csv-file-with-quotes-as-text-delimiter-using-string-split):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "\"Gates Nissan of Richmond\" , \"L2T Media, Llc\" , \"7000000\", \"--\"";
    String[] splitted = s.split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");
    for(String item : splitted) {
        item.replaceAll(",", "");
    }
}
```

Comment: Will this work with escaped quotation marks as well?