# Splitting a CSV File in Java that has extra commas and extra quotes in them

Tags: java, csv, split

I need to parse a one-column CSV file that not only has extra commas but also some of the names include extra quotes.  I have looked over and have read the other previous questions and one of the best answers was [Achintya Jha's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738918/splitting-a-csv-file-with-quotes-as-text-delimiter-using-string-split).  However, that solution does not seem to work in my case.  An example is that the name

```
ADAMS COUNTY SHERIFF "ADAMS COUNTY SHERIFF'S OFFICE, CO"
```

is  being printed out as:

```
ADAMS COUNTY SHERIFF 
"ADAMS COUNTY SHERIFF'S OFFICE, CO"
```

It is splitting at the correct spots and is taking care of the extra commas but not it is hitting the extra quotes and is splitting there now too, so `String csvSplitBy = ",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)";` will not work. Does anyone know of another way to handle this issue in Java? Other have asked this question for an answer in other languages but I could not find any, other then the one i linked to, about Java. Thanks!

### This is my Java code:

```
package csvdatacompareapplication;
import java.io.*;

public class CSVDataCompareApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BufferedReader br = null;
        BufferedReader br2 = null;
        String customerListAllCustomers = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\customerListAllCustomers.csv";
        String customerListToRemove = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\customerListToRemove.csv";
        String line = "";
        String csvSplitBy = ",";

        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(customerListAllCustomers));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                // use comma as separator
                //String [] customersAll = line.split(csvSplitBy);
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

### First few lines of my .CSV File

```
ADAMS COUNTY SHERIFF'S OFFICE, CO
ADAMSON POLICE PRODUCTS
ADAN DAVILA
ADAPT SECURE
ADDISON PD - MIKE VINCENT
ADDISON POLICE - IL
ADDISON PORTER
ADIN MCGARVIE
ADMIRAL FIRE & SAFETY
ADMON IRAMIYA
ADRIAN DANG
ADRIAN HUMPHRIES
ADRIAN KEPKA
ADRIAN SALDANA
ADRIAN SOLER
ADRIAN YORK
ADRIENNE BAKER
ADRIENNE MOOS
ADS INC.
ADS, INC
```

**I updated my java code and now this is what prints out**

```
"ADAMS COUNTY SHERIFF'S OFFICE, CO"
ADAMSON POLICE PRODUCTS
ADAN DAVILA
ADAPT SECURE
ADDISON PD - MIKE VINCENT
ADDISON POLICE - IL
ADDISON PORTER
ADIN MCGARVIE
ADMIRAL FIRE & SAFETY
ADMON IRAMIYA
ADRIAN DANG
ADRIAN HUMPHRIES
ADRIAN KEPKA
ADRIAN SALDANA
ADRIAN SOLER
ADRIAN YORK
ADRIENNE BAKER
ADRIENNE MOOS
ADS INC.
"ADS, INC"
```

**Why did the quotes get placed in?**

Comment: The way I would handle this is to iterate over each character. I do not think that `split` would be able to handle all double-quote characteristics. (quoted fields can contain commas, and non-quoted fields can contain quotes mid-way) Also it is possible to have line returns within a double-quoted string, but that may be beyond the scope of your program.

Comment: Instead of using regular expression try a library which reads CSV like Apache CSV Parser https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/user-guide.html

Comment: how does your input file look exactly? you sure it is csv?

Comment: A *"1 column CSV file"* that doesn't correctly quote special characters like `"` and `,`, is **not a CSV file**. It is a text file, with one name per line. Just use a `BufferedReader` and the `readLine()` method.

Comment: @Andreas it is in a .CSV format because it is an export from a report I built to display all of our customer names.

Comment: Then the report export feature is flawed, or it is not a CSV file, but maybe a tab-separated text file. With only 1 column, you will of course not see any tab characters.

Comment: @TamasHegedus yes I am sure it is a CSV. My initial problem was that I had extra commas within the fields that was messing me up. So I checked out the solution that I linked to handle the issue , which it did, but it also caused another issue because it is now splitting at the quotes in the fields. I guess my major issue is dealing with extra commas in the .CSV file

Comment: @Andreas I understand why you think that. It is a .CSV file though. I think there is a slight misunderstanding and I aplogize for that. The file is a .CSV file- my issue is that it has extra commas that are throwing off my .split java code.

Comment: If the file has a line like `abc "def"`, then it is not a *valid* CSV file.

Comment: Please show us the first few lines of your input file. Open it with a text editor (not with excel), and paste it please so we can see the actual format.

Comment: @Andreas Oh now I understand! You are correct. Let me show you lines in my CSV file. Thank you for your patience and for teaching. I wil update my question with my CSV file screenshot.

Comment: No screenshot please. Just paste in the first few lines.

Comment: The lines are posted of the first few lines in the .CSV File. It has extra commas. I believe it was the answer to the link I posted that added the quotes to my java code. I believe.

Comment: Do you have to split at all?  It looks like the customer name is the only thing on each line.  Why not just `while ((customer = br.readLine()) != null) { System.out.println(customer); }` ?  I agree with [Andreas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37169603/splitting-a-csv-file-in-java-that-has-extra-commas-and-extra-quotes-in-them#comment61874401_37169603) --- _even if the extension is CSV_, you don't need to use a CSV parser if there's only one column of data in the file.

Comment: @cxw You are correct. And your while loop worked. I was under the assumption that though it was 1 column of data it still had to be "split" because it was a .CSV file (which it is). When I do `while ((line = br. readLine()) != null) { System.out.println(line); }` It does print out the cells now but for  whatever reason it is now printing out with quotes

Comment: First CSV example is **not** a *valid* CSV file, because it contains unquoted commas. Second CSV example is good, and any CSV parser should now be able to read it for you. See [suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37169603/splitting-a-csv-file-in-java-that-has-extra-commas-and-extra-quotes-in-them#comment61874246_37169603) by @11thdimension above.

Comment: @Andreas interesting! That's very odd because it is a direct export from my DBMS. It should save them/convert them to proper .CSV. Although I did not know about the unquoted commas. Thank you for all of your help and teachings! Maybe it is because I tried to export my report as "formatted for exporting". Let me try and export it without hitting that.

Comment: It seems to be saving it as a comma delimted file. Would that be causing the issue?

Comment: @Ashton if your file doesn't contain any escaped quotes you could try `line.replaceAll("^(")?((?(1)[^"]+|[^,\\n]+))", "$2");`

Comment: @JamesBuck how would that look in regards to my code? That may work!

Comment: @Ashton see what happens when you do `System.out.println(line.replaceAll(...));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5221149/andreas) and [Tamas Hegedus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5108418/tamas-hegedus) for helping you clarify the question!  Try:

```
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(customerListAllCustomers));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            // one column, so don't need to use comma as separator
            String line2 = line.replaceAll("^\"","").replaceAll("\"$","").replaceAll("\\\"","\"");
            System.out.println(line2);
```

The `replaceAll` calls strip leading quotes (`^\"`) and trailing quotes (`\"$`), and then unescape the remaining quotes (`\\\"`).

Comment: Wonderful! This got rid of the extra quotes! Now is there a way to save the output to a new.csv file? Thank you all!

Comment: Also, I just realized I may not be able to do this because it is not an ArrayList right?

Comment: @Ashton, I'm not sure I understand your question regarding `ArrayList`.  Just like you did for this question, give it a try, and look for help in existing answers or other sites.  If you get stuck, post another question with the code you're having trouble with. :)  Good luck!