# How to remove special characters including commas, quotes from a column string in apache beam (Google cloud dataflow)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have few records in my CSV which contain special characters.
Consider an example for employee data in CSV.
columns
id,name,designation, address, salary
1001, Peter Occon, Manager, "42, Willis Way St, Waterloo, Ohio, US", 5000
and so on...

As you can see, I need to remove the commas and quotes present in the 'address' column in the apache beam.

Comment: Have you considering first splitting by `"` and then by `, `? This way you can first parse the address.

Answer (score 1):

This was acheived using this -

beam.Regex.replace_all(r'"([^"]*)"',lambda x:x.group(1).replace(',',''))

NOTE - this should be written before 'split' function in the pipeline.

Comment: You could also consider using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738918/splitting-a-csv-file-with-quotes-as-text-delimiter-using-string-split to properly handle double quotes and preserve the commas in your addresses.