# Using delimiter in nextToken() with multiple delimiter in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to work with a String that is structured like this:

```
3882027944,Yes,"A specific website or app (please provide the answer)",
"Weather Underground, also local tv news half the time.",
"Somewhat likely","30 - 44", Male, "$10,000 to $24,999",
"West North Central"
```

(Linebreaks for clarity, not in the original text)

I've been trying to do this using the `nextToken()` function in Java. I'm trying to split the string by each part between the commas. However, if a String contains a comma (e.g. `Weather Underground, also local...`), it should not split there.

So my question is: Is there a way to split on a combination of tokens, so that I can split on `","` instead of every seperate `,`?

Comment: Here is your solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800494/parse-csv-with-double-quote-in-some-cases

Comment: By the way, do you mean you use `StringTokenizer`?

Comment: hmm.. thanks... but i don't think this is kind of the solutions i was looking for, i'm actually using trying to use tokenizer to read in bits and pieces of the whole string, as there are 100~1000 lines of similar data string, and using the pattern matching i don't think it will work the way i wanted to..

Comment: i thought nextToken(delimiter) also works? if i'm expecting different delimiter for each token...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use split instead of a tokenizer

From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

> StringTokenizer is a **legacy** class that is retained for
>   compatibility reasons although **its use is discouraged** in new code.
>   It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split
>   method of String or the java.util.regex package instead.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String delims = "\",\"";
        String splitString = "one\",\"two,\",\"three\",\"four\",\",five";

        String[] tokens = splitString.split(delims);
        int tokenCount = tokens.length;
        for (int j = 0; j < tokenCount; j++) {
            System.out.println("Split Output: "+ tokens[j]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: yeah i guess this would be a better solution, i just thought there might be a way around using the tokenizers . Thanks.