# Parsing csv file with fields enclosed in double quotation marks and a field contains double quotes

Tags: java, csv

I am parsing a CSV file with opencsv and all the fields are separated by commas and are enclosed in double quotation marks. If a field contains double quotes, open CSV doesn't parse the file properly. An example below:

`"aaa","b""bb","ccc"`

Right now the constructor I am using is:

```
reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFile), ',', '"', 1);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse CSV with double quote in some cases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800494/parse-csv-with-double-quote-in-some-cases)

Comment: Use the `CSVReader(FileReader, ',')` constructor then parse the `String[]` yourself.  One of them will be `"b""bb"` then handle it however you want.  You'll just have to deal with the quotes now through `Regexp` or whatever.

Comment: Which opencsv version are you using ? I have tested it, it parse perfectly and here is the output `[aaa, b"bb, ccc]`

Comment: Version 3.8. IS your constructor the exact same?