# Loading and editing a CSV file in Java into a List

Tags: java, list, csv

I'm working on a private project where i need to load a CSV file, keep it in the program and edit if needed.

The file looks like this:

```
ID;Name;Last Login;RevState;List
157;Guy;"01.11.19";false;"tag, cup, sting"
A60;Dud;"07.10.19";true;"ice, wood, cup, tag"
1D5;Wilfred;"11.11.19";true;"beer, food, cup, shower"
```

I will only ever have a single csv file loaded. I need to be able to edit every single data point. I need to be able to retrieve all the information of one "category", e.g. get all names.

So what I plan to do is load the CSV via

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(file.csv))
```

Create a class that holds the information of a line

```
public class User 
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String lastLogin;
    private String list;
    public getter and setter methods
```

Create a list

```
private List<User> csvList = new List<User>();
```

And then store every line as

```
while (file.hasNextLine())
    [...] parse the line
    User user = new User(id, name, lastLogin, list);
    csvList.add(user);
```

Would this work, or is there a better method that I can't think of right now?

Comment: Create a method to write at file and another one to read from file. The one that reads from file should create your data structures independently of the file you read from, provided its formatted correctly. Your write method should use your data structures to generate the file from scratch, and ensure it's created in the format your readFromFile method expects. That's all there is to it.

Comment: @JustADude https://www.callicoder.com/java-read-write-csv-file-opencsv/ see this link it can help you. There is a library to read write csv for java.

Comment: You could just read the CSV into a MySQL DB (through CLI) and then use hibernate... But that depends on the size of your project and how robust the solution is meant to be.

Comment: I'll look into opencsv, thanks for the link. The project is on the small side and will stay in java, so I'm not going to use MySQL.

Comment: I recommend using a third-party parser for parsing CSV files like [Apache Commons CSV](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-csv) for example. CSV, like any other format, has some rules (e.g. escaping) that you may not be aware of now that might result in future bugs.

Comment: Check this https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-and-parse-csv-file-in-java/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing CSV in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908012/parsing-csv-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Here it goes:

```
public class User {

  private int id;
  private String name;
  private String email;
  private String phone;

  public User() {

  }

  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getEmail() {
    return email;
  }

  public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
  }

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "User{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", email='" + email + '\'' +
            ", phone='" + phone + '\'' +
            '}';
 }
}
```

Main class

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Main {

public static void main(String [] args ) throws Exception {

    List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
    String path = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(path+"/src/"+"users.csv");
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream));
    String line = "";
    int lines = 0;
    while((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
        lines++;
        String [] columns = line.split(",");
        if(lines ==1 ) {
            continue;
        }
        else {
            User user = new User();
            user.setId(Integer.parseInt(columns[0]));
            user.setName(columns[1]);
            user.setEmail(columns[2]);
            user.setPhone(columns[3]);

            users.add(user);
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i< users.size();i++){
        System.out.println(users.get(i));
    }
  }
}
```

And users.csv file

Id, Name, Email, Phone

1,  John, john.doe@gmail.com, 123456789

Comment: That is the thing: your CSV parser works with your example data. It will break with the example data provided by the user. Writing a CSV parser that **really** works with arbitrary CSV input is much harder than splitting on ",". Hint: the example data uses strings in "quotes, that have commas". Uups.

Comment: Thus the real answer is: to use an existing CSV parser library. Or being willing to spend at least 1 week of fulltime work to get your own parser "good enough".